# How can i write this query in cakephp-3 way?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Raw sql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT p.id,
          p.title,
          p.mark,

     (SELECT max(created)
      FROM comments c
      WHERE c.post_id=p.id
        AND c.mark=1) AS latest_at
   FROM posts p) AS Post
WHERE Post.latest_at IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY latest_at DESC LIMIT 10
```

I have these two tables:

```
$postsTable = TableRegistry::get('Posts');
$comments = TableRegistry::get('Comments');
```

I have made the inner query in cakephp-3 way:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.title,
       p.mark,
       (SELECT max(created)
          FROM comments c
          WHERE c.post_id=p.id AND c.mark=1) AS latest_at
       FROM posts p
```

Cakephp-3 way inner sql with the cakephp-3 querybuilder(is the query below correct?):

```
        $subquery = $comments->find();
        $subquery->select([$subquery->func()->max('created')])
                ->from(['c'=>'comments'])
                ->where(['c.post_id=p.id','mark=1']);

        $pquery = $postsTable->find()
        ->select(['p.id','p.title','p.mark','latest_at'=>$subquery])
        ->from(['p'=>'posts']);
```

How can i write the outer select query in cakephp-3 way? (select * from (derived table) )

Thanks in advance. Any answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This might help you http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your question, this is how to use a subquery in the from part of another query:

```
$query = $this->MyTable->connection()->newQuery();
$query->select('*')->from(['Post' => $subqueryObject])->fetchAll('assoc');
```

This will return arrays for results, if you know what type of entity it should be hydrating to, then do this:

```
$query = $this->Posts
    ->find()
    ->select($listOfFields)
    ->from(['Posts' => $subqueryObject], true)
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very complicated solution to a very simple problem (i.e. getting the post with the latest comment).

A better query would be:

```
 select posts.* from posts join comments on (comments.post_id = posts.id) group by posts.id order by comments.created desc limit 1
```

The ORM way of doing this query would be:

```
$post = $postsTable
    ->find()
    ->select(['Posts.id', 'Posts.title', 'Posts.mark', 'Comments.created'])
    ->leftJoinWith('Comments', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['Comments.mark' => true]);
    }))
    ->group(['Posts.id'])
    ->order(['Comments.created' => 'desc'])
    ->first();
```

Comment: Your query doesn't return the expected result. It doesn't return the same result as my sql query. My query returns expected result. It is because you did group by `posts.id` then `order by comments.created`. It comes with the first comment of a post. There are multiple comments for one post. You have to first take the comment with the latest date that means the last comment for that post.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394034/how-can-i-write-equivalent-sql-query-with-join

Answer (score -1):

For special situations, cakephp allows you to write RAW SQL and keep within the cakephp way. Just create a function in your model and you can write that query the way it is by placing it in `$this->query("...")` .

Example (in model):

```
public function getPosts(){
      $this->query("SELECT * FROM Posts AS Post"); //put complext query here
}
```

Then in Controller:

```
$posts = $this->Post->getPosts();
```