# How can i write equivalent sql query with join?

Tags: mysql, sql

Raw sql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT p.id,
          p.title,
          p.mark,

     (SELECT max(created)
      FROM comments c
      WHERE c.post_id=p.id
        AND c.mark=1) AS latest_at
   FROM posts p) AS Post
WHERE Post.latest_at IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY latest_at DESC LIMIT 10
```

I'm trying to write equivalent sql query with join. How can i do it?

```
mysql> describe posts;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body        | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tags        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mark        | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| created     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe comments;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body     | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mark     | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| created  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Any answer will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.mark,
       c.latest_at     
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT post_id, MAX(created) AS latest_at
   FROM comments
   WHERE mark = 1
   GROUP BY post_id 
) AS c ON c.post_id = p.id 
WHERE c.latest_at IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY c.latest_at DESC LIMIT 10
```

or just this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.mark,
       c.latest_at     
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT post_id, MAX(created) AS latest_at
   FROM comments
   WHERE mark = 1
   GROUP BY post_id 
) AS c ON c.post_id = p.id 
ORDER BY c.latest_at DESC LIMIT 10
```

because the `c.latest_at IS NOT NULL` predicate of the `WHERE` clause of the first query turns `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.title,
       p.mark,
       c.latest_at
  FROM posts p LEFT OUTER JOIN (select post_id, max(created) latest_at
                                from comments 
                                where mark=1
                                group by post_id
                               ) c ON (c.post_id=p.id)
WHERE c.latest_at IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY c.latest_at DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Why `LEFT` when `c.latest_at IS NOT NULL`? This is the same as an Inner Join. And why exactly the same answer that Giorgos Betsos posted half an HOUR AGO?

Comment: of course you could use INNER JOIN in this case, but what if you remove the WHERE clause? (LEFT seems more adequate for this case I think). Also, yes, it's basically the same answer as Giorgos postet, sry.

Comment: If you remove the WHERE-clause a LEFT join will be correct, but this is not what the OP asked for :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to rewrite that query.  The correlated subquery should have fine performance.  But, you can do:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.mark, c.maxc
FROM posts p JOIN
     (SELECT post_id, MAX(created) as maxc
      FROM comments 
      WHERE mark = 1
      GROUP BY post_id
      ORDER BY maxc DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) c
     ON c.post_id = p.id
ORDER BY maxc DESC;
```

Notes:

- The correlated subquery is now an aggregation query.
- This uses `JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN` because (presumably) you only want rows that have a comment.
- The `LIMIT` is in the subquery, so the `JOIN` is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think a common table expression would also work (not sure about performance):

```
WITH cte_latest (id, maxCreated)
AS
(
   SELECT post_id, MAX(created)
   FROM comments
   WHERE mark = 1
   GROUP BY post_id 
)
SELECT  * -- Whetever columns you need here
FROM    posts p
INNER JOIN cte_latest
    ON p.id = cte_latest.id
```

Comment: Is `with` keyword available in mysql?